# What's the best way to define custom id generation as default in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to switch my domain classes to use a variable length UUID for their ids. I don't want to simply display sequential ids on the URL for people to try and mess with. I've written a custom version of the Java UUID method to allow for variable length so I can have shorter ids for models that won't grow large.

I found this thread that explained how to modify the default mapping so I can change to 'assigned'.
[Modify Id generation for a Grails Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033807/modify-id-generation-for-a-grails-plugin)

What's the best way to also configure a default beforeInsert (to generate the custom UUID) and tell Grails I want to use strings for ids instead of integers?

I tried adding *grails.gorm.default.beforeInsert* to the config but that didn't work.

Comment: ataylor's answer below is the right way to do it in grails, but I've normally left the database generated IDs alone and added a different string/GUID field on the objects that needed some sort of correlation ID that might get exposed to the end user.

That way, you get the normal join/foreign key behavior that grails/hibernate and databases have been tuned for (and writing SQL is easier), but when you need that external ID, you've got that too.

Comment: That's what I've done before, but I read that you lose out on default cache that way since it does it by the id. And since I try not to do stuff against the db (or we have an alternate key) I'm gonna give this a shot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make grails use strings for the ids, just declare a property `String id`.  To populate it with a custom UUID, I'd use a hibernate id generator instead of beforeInsert.  Create a class that extends `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator`, then add an id generator mapping like this to your domain class:

```
class MyIdGenerator extends IdentifierGenerator {
    Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) {
        return MyUUID.generate()
    }
}

class MyDomain {
    String id
    static mapping = {
        id generator:"my.package.MyIdGenerator", column:"id", unique:"true"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but it's still showing up in searches. This currently the best way to do this, circa Grails 2.3. (I'm using postgres, so notice the "pg-uuid" type. Adapt this to your particular data store).

```
UUID uuid    
static mapping = {
    uuid generator: 'uuid2', type: 'pg-uuid'
    ...
}
```