# Auto Increment of CustomID in Grails 3

Tags: java, oracle, grails, groovy

How to apply auto increment of customize ID in Grails 3 like-

```
STD_ID
-----------
REG-17-0001
REG-17-0002
REG-17-0003
```

Comment: Is the prefix always going to be REG-17- ?

Comment: 'REG' is My default Prefix and '17' is the last 2 digit of current year.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259746/whats-the-best-way-to-define-custom-id-generation-as-default-in-grails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to define custom id generation as default in Grails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259746/whats-the-best-way-to-define-custom-id-generation-as-default-in-grails)

Comment: I followed this one but doesn't work. My process is different where ID will increase as 4 digit of integer and remaining string will same.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `generator` in your `mapping` closure:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'hilo'...
}
```

See the [documentation1](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html), [documentation2](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#identity).

Comment: This is Hibernate’s built in hilo generators which uses a separate table to generate ids. But I want to generate this STD_ID with ID column on same table.